# Is it lawful to do business with non-Muslim businesses like Sainsbury and Tesco?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, business

I know doing business with non-Muslims is allowed, but scholars have said helping Zionist businesses is haram and I have seen the reasoning behind the fatwa which makes sense. However in the UK, businesses like Sainsbury and Tesco are not Zionistic compared to the same extent as Coka Cola, but are also not your humble non-Muslim businesses with honest livings and activities.

I have a beverage business, but to make real volumes of sales I have to make it available in these big supermarkets.  Is it lawful for me and can you provide a reason?

I want this business to thrive but fear in Allah more and do not want to compromise myself. A portion of my profits are even allocated to a charity, so the more successful my business is, effectively the more lives I save insha allah.

Comment: The Quranic term Kafir is not applicable on present day non-Muslims.

Comment: @afnrf Can you explain what you mean by that??

Comment: The word haram is thrown around a lot. In modern day society, in the days of open trade, how can helping "Zionist businesses is haram" be possible? Your beverage business is most likely also using MANY other companies (machines, accounts, raw products and so on..). 

Just go on ahead and conduct business to feed your family and put a roof over your head. These types of threads really bother me as the logic/rational is completely thrown out the window.

Comment: @Erciyes "A person becomes a Kafir when he denies the truth in spite of being convinced that it is the truth." Ref: http://bit.ly/1uI9ddq

Comment: I agree with @afnrf . The Quran is clearly discribing the kuffar as people with arrogance, denying the truth and ignoring it. 

71:7 
"And indeed, every time I invited them that You may forgive them, they put their fingers in their ears, covered themselves with their garments, persisted, and were arrogant with [great] arrogance."

The word kafir can mean "to hide", to hide what? The truth, i.e to deny the truth.

Comment: Just read the verses at 7:130 - 7:136 (Al-A'raf). The Quran is filled with descriptions like these.

Comment: 7:146 "I will turn away from My signs those who are arrogant upon the earth without right; and if they should see every sign, they will not believe in it. And if they see the way of consciousness, they will not adopt it as a way; but if they see the way of error, they will adopt it as a way. That is because they have denied Our signs and they were heedless of them."

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be an issue with doing business with countries you are at war with (let alone companies that support them). The prophet (PBUH) never prohibited such thing when they were at war with the Kufar in Mecca and the Companions never did so as well.

Any scholars who are saying that it is forbidden are doing it without any backup proof from the actions of the Prophet PBUH/companions or text from the Quran.

Answer (score -1):

Initially, it could be profitable for you to know that **in accordance with the Fatwa of Ayatollah Khamenei as a Marja’al-Taqlid of Shia Islam, working at the jobs which are related to the haram jobs, is not permissible; and its income would be haram as well. So, in the first step you ought to be sure that your business doesn't consider as an occupation which could be related to selling of haram thing(s). As a result, seemingly, if you are certain that those beverage and other things of the store are not considered as haram items, then it seems that it doesn't have any matter.**

But at the second step, in regard to your inquiry about your job which could be related to Israel (Zionist), according to the Fatwa of Imam Khomeini, (as a response to an inquiry which was asked that Is the employment of Muslims in Jewish companies and institutes, knowing that they aid Israel, permissible or not? What if we don’t know if they aid Israel or not and receive our salary on a daily basis? Then, the answer of [Imam Khomeini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhollah_Khomeini) was:

> Employment isn't permissible. The money they receive from working
>   there is also haram, and in the case of uncertainty, they shouldn’t go
>   into these institutes.

So, perhaps the reason which makes the business as a haram act (with them), it could be related to help the countries which are considered as the enemy of Islam.. Since for example, Ayatollah Hadawi-Tehrani also has the same Fatwa that:

> Having business with foreigner people or Kufar or Ahl-al-Ketab
>   (primarily) is permissible. Of course it wouldn't be permissible if
>   there is a  corruption such as helping to the enemy of Islam in the
>   trade.

Eventually, as the last part of your issue that you mentioned regarding the issue of  charity, it could be necessary to point that although it is considered as a positive act (charity), but it could not miss the corruption of the main action.

**Reference:**

http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa566

http://www.hadavi.info/fa/archive/question/fa817

Comment: Jzk allah once again, but i already knew that much, this is a bit more grey than black and white, it is NOT a zionist company that directly aids Israel, nor is it a small business owned by a kufar, it is a corporate supermarket that is taxed and sells haram as a supermarket has both halal and haram meat, but my beverage is a halal dairy product i just want to sell in there super market, not aid for example countries foreign policies nor zionism.

Comment: right, but anyway I reckon it couldn't be without any problem, since anyway you mentioned that it sells both halal and haram things ... unfortunately at the moment I have no sufficient time to do search and could help you. hopefully be able to help you later. Good luck mate